# Наложение лого поверх фона

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, как наложение лого поверх фона(background).  Хочу чтобы было не все изображение,  а только текст, которые ляжет поверх фона.  Пробовал с прозрачным фоном картинки, не помогло.

---

Ребят,  мне пока тяжело понять на словах.  Может кто-нибудь написать маленький код?  Чтобы был какой-то фон и поверх него лежал текст в виде изображения.

Comment: Вообще ничего непонятно...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простой пример. Фон синий - по верх картинка.

```css
.test{
  width:100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color:blue;
  background-image: url('https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/original/56ffca99c57d3153d72f68d1.png');
  background-position:center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Делаешь лого png или svg картинкой, без заливки. А потом позиционируешь, так как тебе надо, например при помощи свойства `position:absolute;`

Comment: Как я понял свойство "position:absolute" это CSS? Извините за такой вопрос.  Недавно начал этим заниматься

Comment: @Elus1ve верно. А можно и в `background-image` закинуть картинку (`.png` или `.svg`), а залить любым цветом через свойство `background-color`.

Comment: @Elus1ve Изображение в студию. И не надо отвечать в виде ответа - есть комментарии.

Comment: @doox911 для примера покажи на этом лого http://cliparthouse.ru/wp-content/uploads/animals/61-animals-ass-1.jpg

Comment: @Elus1ve нужно `.png` с прозрачным фоном.

Comment: @doox911 можешь взять любое изображение в инете?  Мне хотя-бы для примера, чтобы понять это.  Просто сейчас не могу скинуть нужное лого так как не за компьютером.